# Dúvida sobre treinamento openCV

Tags: python, opencv

Em um aprendizado de máquina deve-se separar os dados em 3 conjuntos, um para treinamento, outro pra validação e outro pra testes com quantidade relativa a 70%, 15% e 15% respectivamente.
Contudo minha dúvida é em relação a quantidade real de imagens/dados para um treinamento ideal de reconhecimento.

Tenho usado o opencv trainscascade para fazer o treinamento, mas infelizmente para o meu projeto eu não possuo um número consideravel de imagens tanto positivas quanto negativas então precisaria de um número mínimo para esses dois tipos de imagens, qual seria?
E quanto aos estágios, estou a par de que quanto mais estágios é colocado como parâmetro mais específico se torna o reconhecimento, o que pode gerar até um treinamento excessivo, então o número de estágios ideal se dá também por volta de 10 e 20 ?

E por último, caso eu faça um treinamento gerando um cascade.xml de data, e em seguida faça outro que complemente esse primeiro cascade é possível anexá-los de alguma forma sem ter que retreinar tudo de novo?

Segue abaixo um exemplo de código para facilitar a visualização dos parâmetros para treinamento:

```
 opencv_traincascade -data 'diretório do cascade' \
-vec 'diretório das imagens POS.vec' \
-bg 'diretório das imagens NEG.txt' \
-numPos x \
-numNeg y \
-numStages z \
-w 24 -h 24 \
-mode ALL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe uma formula exata para se calcular qual a quantidade de treinamento que um modelo precisa receber para cair em um "treinamento excessivo" ou overfitting que apesar de ser um termo em inglês é o nome mais difundido por aqui, é necessário testa-lo de forma gradual para saber qual deles obteve o melhor desempenho.

Imagino que a sua duvida tenha surgido, por medo de gerar overfitting, que é basicamente o nome dado a um modelo que se "acostumou" tanto ao padrão de amostras do seu dataset de treino que tem dificuldades em identificar ou predizer qualquer amostra que esteja fora do seu dataset.

No seu caso é fácil identificar qual a quantidade ideal de treino pois como você mencionou a própria biblioteca separa 15% das amostras para fins de testes ou seja são amostras que não estarão presentes em seu dataset de treino, isso assegura que os valores retornados nos resultados não estão sendo influenciados pelas amostras do treino ( desde que as amostras de testes não sejam iguais as amostras de treino), portanto, você pode começar treinando com 10 estágios e depois comparar os resultados com um treino feito com 20, caso o resultado com 20 tenha melhorado ainda pode haver espaço para melhora então tente 30, agora caso o resultado com 10 tenha sido melhor tente encontrar entre 10 e 20 qual o melhor resultado, e assim até se dar por satisfeito com os resultados.

**Obs**: Usei como exemplo 10 e 20 estágios pois eles foram mencionados na pergunta, o ideal é se trabalhar com um range bem maior e ir afunilando conforme os resultados forem aparecendo.